# Microservices Architecture for deployment with no SPF(Single Point Failure)

Tags: architecture, microservices

I am trying to deploying my microservices architecture to production env.

Now
I have 15 services, 1 Facade Layer,

Facade Layer calls services , gets data , aggregates them and generate final result.

Also services calls each other(rarely but yes, they call each other).

Now I don't want any Single Point of Failure.
So
I have decided that I will have 5 Boxes(5 high end servers).

A, B , C , D ,E
A will be LVS(for Load Balancing)
B & C will host Facade layer.
So when request came for Facade, it will come from A and load balanced to B & C.

Now D & E boxes host services(each box has all 15 services).

So B & C box will contain each one haproxy instance also, since when Facade Layer calls services, it will be load balanced. each box ha will act as active for Facade Layer on same box & passive for Facade Layer on differnt box.

But my question is how should I allow my services to call each other?
Should I use separate haproxy on D & E box? Should I use the one on B & C.?

Comment: You could use Docker-swarm and scale thes services accordingly. For databases you should use replication. Use HAProxy only for the front-faced servers (Docker-swarm does not have stickyness on HTTP client connections, it uses only round-robin).

Comment: Yes, but inutially I have to go without docker. So can you tell me what fits best here? I mean for services calls?

Comment: well, as you need HA, you need also service discovery.

Comment: Yes, but without service discovery also, I can do it with with hard code mappings in haproxy config. then how?

Comment: without external SD is hard. In this case the clients need to perform SD as they need to know the services' addresses and they also be aware of HA.

Comment: clients only facade layer by LVS. so this is just one endpoint. Facade layer knows about all services(haproxy) which knows about all services(static). same for all services. So with static list  and without SD, everything should works fine. can you just tell me should i use separate HA on box D & E or use the same on B & C and how?

Comment: LVS == Linux Virtual Server?

Comment: yes for Load balacing, LVS (Linux Virtual Server)

Comment: But you have only one node/machine for LVS? `A will be LVS(for Load Balancing) `

Comment: Its actually will be two(Active & passive). Forget to mention